# How to merge two dataframes with same column name but may have same data in variables in R?

Tags: r

I want to ask how do I merge this two data frame?

df1:

```
Name   Type   Price
A       1      NA
B       2      2.5
C       3      2.0
```

df2:

```
Name   Type   Price
A       1      1.5
D       2      2.5
E       3      2.0
```

As you can see from both df, they have same column names and one row with the same value in "Name" which is A but df1 doesn't have the price whereas df2 has. I want to achieve this output such that they merge if the value in "Name" is the same

```
Name   Type   Price
A       1      1.5
B       2      2.5
C       3      2.0
D       2      2.5
E       3      2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do a `full_join` on `df1` and `df2` by `Name` and using  `coalesce` on `Type` and `Price` get the first non-NA value from those columns.

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, by = 'Name') %>%
   mutate(Type = coalesce(Type.x, Type.y), 
          Price = coalesce(Price.x, Price.y)) %>%
   select(names(df1))

#  Name Type Price
#1    A    1   1.5
#2    B    2   2.5
#3    C    3   2.0
#4    D    2   2.5
#5    E    3   2.0
```

And similar in base R :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'Name', all = TRUE), 
           Price = ifelse(is.na(Price.x), Price.y, Price.x), 
           Type = ifelse(is.na(Type.x), Type.y, Type.x))[names(df1)]
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), Type = 1:3, Price = c(NA, 2.5, 2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "D", "E"
), class = "factor"), Type = 1:3, Price = c(1.5, 2.5, 2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to rbind the data frames together, then remove rows with NA values for Price, and order by Name.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(rbind(df1, df2))[!is.na(Price)][order(Name)]
#    Name Type Price
# 1:    A    1   1.5
# 2:    B    2   2.5
# 3:    C    3   2.0
# 4:    D    2   2.5
# 5:    E    3   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `merge` + `ocmplete.cases`

```
dfout <- subset(u <- merge(df1,df2,all= TRUE),complete.cases(u))
```

which yields

```
> dfout
  Name Type Price
1    A    1   1.5
3    B    2   2.5
4    C    3   2.0
5    D    2   2.5
6    E    3   2.0
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), Type = 1:3, Price = c(NA, 2.5, 2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "D", "E"
), class = "factor"), Type = 1:3, Price = c(1.5, 2.5, 2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```